# Piping the output of a bash script after redirecting stderr

Tags: logs, pipe, io-redirection

because of the way my hoster does things I have to use a system for services.

This service has a run file which it executes and pipes into a second run file. But I use a (given) python package that logs to stderr instead of stdout and I can't get it to do what I want.

So I have a run script for my service:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/webapp/PriceList
exec python3.4 ~/webapp/PriceList/src/main.py
```

which is piped into the run of the logging system:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec multilog t ./main
```

But the pipe doesn't connect stderr (as expected).
So after googling I appended a redirection to my run:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/webapp/PriceList
exec python3.4 ~/webapp/PriceList/src/main.py 2>&1
```

But this does not solve my problem: My own outputs (to stdout using pythons print) are logged as expected. The stderr output is not logged.

If I redirect my modified runscript into two files, it shows that there is no redirection (stderr is still on stderr). How do I have to modify my redirection to work?

Comment: `exec ... 2>&1` does indeed join standard error into standard out. So something else is awry.

Comment: Any chance the python script is closing stderr and re-opening it as a file? Look for a call to `dup2()` in the code. Any idea where the stderr output *is* going? Another thought: perhaps your hoster's run file is redirecting stderr this way before starting your code.

Comment: Could be that the python script only prints debugging info if stdout is a tty? You may try that locally or try whether this simple service script  would work `ls --invalid 2>&1`.  Another python issue I know from experience is that it may be helpful to use  `python -u` to not buffer the output.

Comment: try   2>&1  exec python2.4 ~/webapp/PriceList/src/main.py

Comment: Can you absolutely confirm that text is being sent to stderr? Replace the script with one that says `import sys; print("Hello, stderr", file=sys.stderr)` to be sure.

Comment: Really stderr? Try this ``exec python3.4 ~/webapp/PriceList/src/main.py > out.log 2> err.log`` and take a look into this logfiles.

Comment: With python being an interpreted scripting language, you can possibly go into `main.py` and add the redirection `2>&1` to any and all code that prints to stderr so you get a true redirection of your output. Not a python master but you could give this a try and see how it works.

Comment: What happen if you use bash instead of sh?

Comment: @xavor yes, what happens if you do: #!/bin/bash instead of #!/bin/sh ?
maybe sh<->python has a problem with redirecting. Why use a SH if you could use a baSH? :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec 2>&1
cd ~/webapp/PriceList
exec python3.4 ~/webapp/PriceList/src/main.py
```

ie : `exec 2>&1` on a separate line, telling to redirect stderr to the same thing stdout is going to (your terminal? or mail if in a crontab?), followed by the cd & exec to replace the existing process with the python3.2 one. Note that I switched to bash instead of sh, for a lower portability but usually a much better reliability. If this works, great, if not some better knowledgeable persons will step in. (I don't have time to do researchs right now on this)